# PHP - Auto detecting home directory through cron job

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script and using Cpanel interface Im creating a cron job that runs this php script every 5 minutes. The question I have is currently I have to manually set the path to the root directory in my php script at the top of the script like so:

```
$root = '/var/home/www/site/';
```

Then I reference any includes/scripts using $root as the path. The problem is I have a dev box I use to test the script, then upload it to the main server. Every time I have to remember to manually change out the $root variable with the correct root path on the main server. Is there a way to do this automatically so I dont have to manually update the scripts? I tried seeing if I can get the ip address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] but the value is blank and the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] value comes up as /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd). It returns the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a cron job, I would guess that the safest way would be to use `dirname ( __FILE__ )` (or, like James and Alix said, for php >= 5.3 `__DIR__`) - it returns you the directory the script being run resides in.

Comment: since PHP 5.3.0 there's `__DIR__` which will return exactly the same as `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: You can also use `__DIR__` instead on PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 0):

You can define environment vars in a crontab file. At the start of the crontab add:

```
MY_BASE_DIR = "/var/home/www/site/"
```

Now in the PHP script you can get hold of this by looking at:

```
$_ENV['MY_BASE_DIR']
```

Knowing that you can either define the same variable on both live/dev servers or you could have the script look for the environment variable using it if it's there or falling back to a default if it's not there.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use either one of these variables to switch between environments:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

> The IP address of the server under
>   which the current script is executing.

---

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

> The name of the server host under
>   which the current script is executing.
>   If the script is running on a virtual
>   host, this will be the value defined
>   for that virtual host.

---

I'm not sure if these are defined under CRON / php-cli, but an alternative approach might be to check if the folder exists:

```
$root = (is_dir('/var/home/www/site/')) ? '/var/home/www/site/' : '/dev/site/';
```

Comment: @Cfreak: Not exactly true, some of them are.

Comment: Be noticed that this answer is unreliable.